# Google Visualization and ASP Update Panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, google-visualization

I'm attempting to build an org chart via google visualization that updates through AJAX calls using an ASP Update panel.  However, instead of the chart refreshing on the ajax update, the chart just disappears. Anybody have any ideas? Thanks

```
<input type="button" id="cmdUpdate" onclick="__doPostBack('panel', '');" value="Update" />
<div id="divGChart" runat="server" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
    <asp:UpdatePanel id="panel" runat="server" >
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="chart_div" runat="server" >
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['orgchart'] });
                    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                    function drawChart() {
                        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
                        data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
                        data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');
                        data.addRows([
                            [{ v: '10131', f: '10131'}, '', '10131'],
                            [{ v: '10132', f: '10132'}, '10131', '10132'],
                            [{ v: '10133', f: '10133'}, '10131', '10133'],
                            [{ v: '10134', f: '10134'}, '10131', '10134']
                        );
                        var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                        chart.draw(data, {allowCollapse: true, allowHtml: true});
                    }    
                </script>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont know if you still have an issue with this, but it might be helpful for others in the future.

This is apparently a known bug that has been fixed in version 1.1
all you need to do is to change

```
google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['orgchart'] });
```

to

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', { packages: ['orgchart'] });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pageLoad()` to re-initialize your script, also move your `jsapi` script reference outside the `UpdatePanel`, no need to reload that on every partial postback:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() //called on all partial postbacks
    {
        google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['orgchart'] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
        data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');
        data.addRows([
            [{ v: '10131', f: '10131'}, '', '10131'],
            [{ v: '10132', f: '10132'}, '10131', '10132'],
            [{ v: '10133', f: '10133'}, '10131', '10133'],
            [{ v: '10134', f: '10134'}, '10131', '10134']
        );
        var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {allowCollapse: true, allowHtml: true});
        }    
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The script is actually written from a custom server control and changes every time the update panel posts back.  Will it still work if the script is different every time?

Comment: Everything inside an UpdatePanel's ContentTemplate tags get replaced on partial postback, assuming your page has everything it needs, it should work fine.

Comment: pageLoad isn't firing on the partial postback.  Is there a reason for this?

Comment: The reason why is that the pageLoad event is overridden earlier in the page.  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Why are you overriding pageLoad?

Comment: I guess overriding is the wrong word.  It's just used later in the page so when I try to use it here it isn't calling the current function.  It's used for a sort of quick select elsewhere.